# wso2bps 3.6.0 async tasks

Tags: wso2, activiti, wso2-business-process

I need to create parallel running service tasks in my process.

Try to create the simplest flow with async property usage:

[image]

With loop cardinality = 5 (for example)

I found that in `activiti.xml` configuration it's required to add this property:

```
    <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true" />
```

But flow still runs in one thread.

What i'm missing?

How to activate async correctly?

Answer (score 1):

1. to activate async parallel execution in the example above - need to set async on `Call Service` and not on `Sub Process`
2. as soon as we use  `async` we have to configure process engine to be async

   otherwise you will meet this king of exception:

   > org.activiti.engine.ActivitiOptimisticLockingException: VariableInstanceEntity[id=15317, name=nrOfActiveInstances, type=integer, longValue=1, textValue=1] was updated by another transaction concurrently

   the parameters of activiti engine on wso2bps stored here: `conf/activiti.xml`

   just add the following properties to  bean id="processEngineConfiguration"

   ```
   <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">
      ...
      <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true" />
      <property name="asyncExecutorEnabled" value="true" />
      ...
   </bean>
   ```

   > warn: don't know if it's feature or bug. *subprocess will catch correctly all thread endings only if you set `async` on `end events` of subprocess...*

after those changes, the process from question works great in multithread  mode.